# Hand editing .ui files inside Qt editor

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've been tweaking my .ui files by hand a lot recently and I'm curious, does anyone know how to turn off read only mode for .ui files in Qt Creator?

In case that's not immediately clear, what I mean is that .ui files (by default) are view-able inside Qt Creator but not write-able... and it's a minor nuisance to go boot up some other xml editor :/

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you mean "Qt Creator", not "Qt editor". There also is a Qt Designer, and I guess you don't mean this one.

Comment: @leemes, yeah, they like to keep it simple. You use Qt Creator to *edit* files, Qt Designer to *create* a ui. Makes sense if you don't think about it. ;) But yes, Qt Editor doesn't exist as far as Google knows. If it did exist, I'm sure it would be used to design something.

Comment: @weberc2 The meaning is more like: With Qt Designer you *design* your application (i.e. UI design) and with Qt Creator you *create* it (i.e. implement). But the word "design" is a bit ambiguous here, since Qt Designer obviously doesn't cover software design, i.e. class diagrams etc.

Comment: @leemes, I understand the intention. The "create" and "design" are both ambiguous words, especially with respect to software. It was a confusing choice of words.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the context menu of any .ui file in the project explorer, click **Open With** and then **Plain Text Editor**. This gives you the same editor but with write mode.

Note that the disabled write mode for ui files when double clicking and changing to "Edit" mode rather than "Design" mode isn't a bug but a feature. Editing ui files by hand can destroy your file. At least, this is what the Qt guys think...

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed the open with option over there!

Comment: @WestleyArgentum I found it accidentally :)

Comment: It's not a feature, it's design flaw. The problem is once again that the developers value their personal opinion over practical developer needs.

Comment: @TomášZato I agree. (Hence the last sentence...)